# Fitting to an Exponential Decay with Constant Background

Tags: exponential-distribution

I'm looking for simple way to fit to an exponential decay with a constant background, so something that looks like:

$y=ae^{-bx}+c$

I have an idea of how to do it without the background. I would just take the log and obtain:

$ln(y)=ln(a)-bx$

And then just use linear algebra to find $ln(a)$ and $b$. I can't seem to do this with the constant background though, because I can't simplify the following:

$ln(y)=ln(ae^{-bx}+c)$

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "use linear algebra" are you using least squares fitting on the log-scale?